# Google Calendar API within Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, google-calendar-api, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to use Google Calendar API within Spring Boot.
in application.yml I've got something like:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: ${g.client.id}
      clientSecret: ${g.client.secret}
      accessTokenUri: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
      userAuthorizationUri: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth
      clientAuthenticationScheme: form
      scope: openid, email, profile, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
    resource:
      userInfoUri: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo
      preferTokenInfo: true
```

I've got my application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class GoogleAuthenticationApplication extends OAuth2SsoDefaultConfiguration {
```

Authentication works and access calendar scope seems to be granted.
I'm looking now for a way to use the token to access a Google Calendar Service
maybe using this?

```
OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate
```

And some classes from Google App Engine??

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Required some code, can you post more code or github url ?

Comment: There is actually not much more code than that. Spring boot allows SSO out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to fist check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) wherein it was stated that your application can use the access token to call Google APIs and can complete this tasks either by using the Google APIs client library for your language, or by directly interacting with the OAuth 2.0 system using HTTP.

More information on how to you can prepare to make an authorized API call can be found in [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount).

In addition to that, you may want to also check this [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/) which gives some guidelines on how you can properly use access token within Spring boot.

You may want to try examples given in the tutorial which shows the use of access token to ask for some personal details or from this [GitHub post](https://github.com/donhenton/google-cal-api).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, the code from github helps although I had checked it already. I do feel there should be a better solution that that.

Comment: @art1go Hey, I'm working on same stuff. Have you got success. If yes then please provide me with some links of you code. I'm actually creating events on Calendar from Backend.